# Run async operations inside gulp job

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using [gulp-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml) to update my html based on html comments. I need to pass, using options, same variables to its engine in this way:

```
gulp.task('buildIndex', ['clean', 'copyStatic'], function () {
    return gulp.src('src/static/index.html').pipe(processhtml({
        data: { name: 'myname' }
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/static'));
});
```

Everything works fine.

Now I need to retrieve 'myname' value using an async task, for example reading it from filesystem. How can I mix it up this new task inside my gulp stream pipes?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved in this way using Q and returning a promise:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
myAsyncTask(function(myName) {
    gulp.src('src/static/index.html').pipe(processhtml({
        data: { name: myName }
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/static')).on('end', function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Don't know if it's the most elegant way, but it works very well.